# How do I properly update recyclerview when using Room

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I'm new to Android development, and I also don't know English very well, I apologize in advance.

I'm developing a notepad. I have two Recycleviews, the first one displays labels and the second one displays notes. For development, I use the MVP pattern, as well as Room.

When the activity starts, I get all the notes from the repository, namely notesDao (LiveData<List>), and sign them in the activity.

```java
     public void settingsNotesList(LiveData<List<Note>> noteList) {
        mActivityBinding.listNotes.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(15));
        mActivityBinding.listNotes.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        mNoteAdapter = new GenericNoteAdapter<>(new DiffUtilNote(),
                R.layout.item_note,
                (binder, model) -> {
                    binder.setNote(model);
                    mActivityBinding.executePendingBindings();
                });

        mActivityBinding.listNotes.setAdapter(mNoteAdapter);
        noteList.observe(this, notes -> {
           mNoteAdapter.submitList(notes);
            });
    }
```

How can I correctly update the list of notes so that when you click on a label, it shows the notes marked with this label?

I implemented it like this: We create `MutableLiveData` in the repository, and assign it ListNotes (a list of all notes), and when you click on the label for `MutableLiveData`, a new list is assigned via (setValue) with the necessary notes and `MutableLiveData` itself has been mastered the observe observer.

This works, but there is one thing, but if you delete a note or add a new one, the list is not updated and notes are not deleted / added.  This is probably due to the fact that from notesDao (room), I get lists of notes List, and not `LiveData`.

(I tried without switching labels, remove `MutableLiveData`, and just sign `LiveData`, then changes occur)

What do you advise?
[Previous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An2yA.jpg)

Comment: Add more details, all parts of code related to the problem. How do you set the query when user selects a tag for example?

Comment: @Kozmotronik https://github.com/pasichDev/My-Notes/tree/2.0.10